# Ubuntu LTS for Website hosting

Tags: websites

I'm new to Linux. Is Ubuntu LTS good for Website Hosting (mainly documents, audios and small duration videos)? 
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. But, I Prefer GUI, is it okay?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is! I suppose you do not need Graphical User Interface (GUI) for your web server, so you should prefer [Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/server) (which is supported until 2021).

Comment: I prefer GUI. Is it okay? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Of course you can use the gui.

Answer (score 0):

The best collection of tutorials has them
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/
 https://www.howtoforge.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is. A lot people include myself use 14.04 on our VPS. I am not quite sure about the status of 16.04 though. cPanel does not work on Ubuntu, just in case you don't know. But you can always try alternatives like Webmin, VestaCP etc